# Call obj for a component

Tags: ios, react-native, mobile, hook, react-props

I'm calling an obj for my index.js screen like that ...

index.js

```
import React from 'react';
import { View, Text } from 'react-native';
import ScreenUsers from './ScreenUsers';


const Users = (props) => {
  const username = props?.route?.params?.user.map(name => (
    name.userDetails.nameUser
  ));

  return (
    <Text>{username}</Text>
    {ScreenUsers()}
  );
}
```

Until then my index.js works, pull the username, however my index has a component from another screen called ScreenUsers.js where I make a list of users. In this other component that is breaking because it does not return what I want.

ScreenUsers.js

```
import React from 'react';
import { View, Text } from 'react-native';

function ScreenUsers(props) {
  const fullnanme = props?.route?params?.user.users;

  return <Text>{fullname}</Text>
}
```

ScreenUsers have route error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you use `ScreenUsers` as component not as `screen`, you can't handle route in this case, if you want to use it as `navigation screen` you must use navigation read [here](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/hello-react-navigation)

and if you want to use it only as `component`
edit this line `{ScreenUsers()}` to

```js
//pass prop fullname down
<ScreenUsers fullname={"user name1"} />

//recieve props fullname
function ScreenUsers(props) {
  return <Text>{props?.fullname}</Text>
}
```

if you already use `ScreenUsers` as `screen in navigation` and you want also to use it as `component` you can do something like this

```js
//pass prop route
<ScreenUsers route={{params : {fullname : "user name1"}} />

//recieve props fullname
function ScreenUsers(props) {
  return <Text>{props?.route?.params?.fullname}</Text>
}
```